If a sequence of functions converges to $0$ a.e. on $[0,1]$, then it has an absolutely summable subsequence
Let $f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable such that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise a.e. on $[0,1]$. I want to show that $(f_{n})$ contains a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ such that $\sum_{k\geq 1}|f_{n_k}(x)|$ converges for almost every $x\in[0,1]$. How can I do this?

Choose $n_k$ such that $\mu (\{x\in [0,1]: |f_{n_k}(x)|<2^{-k} \})>1-2^{-k}$.  Define $A_k=\{x\in [0,1]: |f_{n_k}(x)|<2^{-k} \}$.  Let $A=\bigcup_{\ell=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=\ell}^{\infty} A_k$.  This set is called the $\liminf$ of the sets $A_k$.  The measure $\mu(A)=\lim_{\ell\to\infty} \mu(\bigcap_{k=\ell}^{\infty} A_k)=1$.  It's straightforward to verify for $x\in A$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |f_{n_k}(x)| < \infty.$$
